# how to speed up building JSON tree using DynamoDB and S3 in Python?

Tags: amazon-s3, tree, amazon-dynamodb

I have a set of JSON messages. Each has a unique id as a field. Some messages are parents of other messages, e.g.

```
{"id":"idX", ..., "parents":["idA", "idB", "idC"]}
```

Each message has other fields but they are not relevant to this question.

Each message is stored in a file on AWS-S3. I also have a DynamoDB table that uses `id` as the key and contains info on where the corresponding message is stored on S3, including path to file and byte offsets of the message to enable direct read.

Given an `id0`, I need to generate the full tree for essentially replacing the id of each parent with the entire contents of its message, recursively. So the example below get expanded like this:

```
{"id":"idX", ..., "parentContents":[{"id":"idA", ...}, {"id":"idB", ...}, {"id":"idC", ...}]}
```

Parents of `id{ABC}` get expanded the same way etc. At the end I end up with a single tree-shaped JSON message with the starting `id0` as its root.

The current algorithm is essentially this (in Python-like pseudocode):

```
def get_message(id):

    # 1. get location info for id from DynamoDB
    # 2. get message for id (mJSON) using location info by direct read from its S3 file
    # 3. Parse the JSON and find list of parent ids (parentIds)
    # 4. Recusrively expand parents:
    for pid in parentIds:
        pJSON = get_message(pid)
        # 4.1. Insert pJSON into mJSON
    # 5. Return full tree for id
    return mJSON
```

So I essentially build the tree in a depth-first fashion. This implementation is slow for large trees. I need to speed it up.

I have not done detailed profiling of my code but I suspect that one bottleneck is single-item reads from DynamoDB at step #4. I played a bit with `batch_get_item` but I noticed that, unlike `get_item` it does not throw exception when one of the keys in the list does not exist in the table. **Is there a different batch-read method that does complain about not-found keys?**

I was thinking of using `batch_get_item` or something similar and refactor the code to read all parent records for given id from DynamoDB at once. **Do you think this might speed things up a lot?**

**Is there a way to a do a batch direct read from multiple S3 files?** Currently, I am using the following block to do a single read:

```
key = s3bkt.lookup(inFile)
line = key.get_contents_as_string(headers={"Range":"bytes="+str(fromOffset)+"-"+str(toOffset)})
```

**Also, do you suspect other bottlenecks?**

Thanks!